# Using scanf to get user inputs for dynamic arrays in c

Tags: c, dynamic-arrays

When I try to get user input for the dynamic array, it stops at the first for loop. It gives me an error that my program has stopped working. Help me out!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int count = 0, sum = 0, *number = NULL, index = 0, size = 0;
    scanf("%d", &size);

    number = (int *)calloc(size, sizeof(int)); //Dynamic allocation

    printf("Enter the elements\n");
    for(index = 0; index < size; index++){
        scanf("%d",number[index]); //Getting the input values from user but i get an error
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int *number; .... scanf("%d",number[index]);` Save time.  Enable compiler warnings,  Faster feedback the posting on SO.

Comment: Generally `scanf` is not a good idea. See [what-can-i-use-for-input-conversion-instead-of-scanf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58403537/what-can-i-use-for-input-conversion-instead-of-scanf/58405772#58405772) for lots of information on this. Using `fgets` in combination with `sscanf` is already a big improvement.

Answer (score 2):

Use this instead:

```
scanf("%d", &number[index]);
```

Note the `&` operator before `number[index]` is needed when using `scanf` for integer input.